# NASM: Unable to assemble 'prefetch0' instruction

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I realize that often it is best not to manually specify prefetching data into the CPU caches. However, I just wanted to write this code to experiment, and make sure I could use it:

```
global start

section .data
msg: db 'hello',0      ; C-style null terminated char array

section .text
start:
    lea rax, [msg]     ; rax = address of 'hello'
    prefetch0 rax      ; fetch data [rax] into cache
    ret                ; return
```

I compiled with NASM, but received the error at `prefetch0 rax` stating:

```
unable to parse: instruction expected.
```

Looking over the forums, it seems this error can sometimes be caused by improper label or section declarations, but I believe mine are in order, and the error is only for that specific instruction.

Just to be thorough, even though I suspected it wouldn't make a difference, I tried every prefetch instruction, i.e. `prefetch1`, `prefetchnta`, etc. The 'nta' version actually printed a different error of wrong operand/instruction combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instruction you are looking for is PREFETCHT0 (there is 'T' before number). You must also give the address in square brackets.